# Prove that $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$ when $f(xy)=xf(x)+yf(y)$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, solution-verification

My attempt:

We let $y=0$, so $f(0)=xf(x)$. When both $x$ and $y$ are $0$, we get $f(0)=0\implies xf(x)=0 \implies f(x)=0.$

Two questions:

Is this rigorous enough?

When we divide both sides by $x$ to get $f(x)=0$, should we account for the case when $x=0$?

Comment: To be complete, you have deduced two things: $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)=0$ when $x \ne 0$. Combined, these give $f(x)=0$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't comment because I don't have 50 reputation, so I'll write in an answer. Your proof is complete.

You showed that $f(0) = 0$, and $xf(x) = 0 \implies f(x) = 0 \forall x \in \mathbb{R^*}$. You already took care of $x=0$ since f(0) = 0.

Answer (score 3):

For $x=0$ take $y=0$ then  $f(0) =0$

For $x\neq 0$ , take $y=0$ then $f(0) =xf(x) $

$xf(x) =0$ and $x\neq 0$ implies $f(x) =0$

Hence $f(x) =0 \space \forall x\in\Bbb{R}$

Answer (score 1):

Let us take $x=y=1$. Then, $f(1)=f(1)+f(1)\implies f(1)=0.$

Let us take only $y=1$. Then for $x\neq 1$ we have
$$f(x)=xf(x)+f(1)=xf(x)\implies (x-1)f(x)=0\implies f(x)=0.$$

Conclusion: $f(x)=0.$